# How to install Thrift to work with Qt-Windows

Tags: windows, qt, thrift

I'm working on the Windows build of a Qt-Widget application. I need to extend my app to interact with a 3rd-party web service that's built on Thrift. I'm not talking about hosting a web service (ie a Thrift-based server); just writing the client to connect to someone else's existing, live Thrift server.

Can anyone provide a checklist of things to integrate Thrift into Qt?

I'm looking for the bits and pieces that need to be installed, and where to get them. I've started the process of trying to get the two to work together, but it seems to be a non-trivial process since Thrift is a *nix-centric library. I was really hoping that there was a static library and some headers for Thrift, like with many other libraries, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I have only found this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1348

Didn't look at it myself though yet.